# Spring Security version 6 issues with SecurityFilterChain

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, h2

I am trying to make a small project with the recent versions of Spring Boot (3.0.6) and Spring Security version 6. The problem is that Spring has deprecated a lot of code regarding establishing auth system.

We used to work with `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and everything worked fine, now we have to use `SecurityFilterChain` instead. I found many examples on the internet where people use `SecurityFilterChain` differently; some use `antMatchers` (deprecated), some `mvcMatchers` (deprecated) and some use `requestMatchers`, which is supported in the last version. Even the official documentations doesn't help at all in this regard. For example, when I use the following code, the h2-console become inaccessible:

```java
package com.example.myproj.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
                .and() 
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/users/**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Here is the h2-console configuration in the `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Here is the `pom.xml` for reference:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myproj</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot and Spring Security</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

So what to do? Some emphasis the use of Lamda DSL for the new version of Spring Security. I need a firm guideline because it's chaos now with Spring Security.

Comment: no the access is forbidden (403), the url is localhost:8080/h2-console

Comment: stupidly i forgot to add : spring.h2.console.enabled=true to the application.properties. Thanks you all! But i am looking for the most recent spring security guide, preferably PDF. Or could someone suggest a good book? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable H2 console, see [9.1.5. Using H2’s Web Console](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#data.sql.h2-web-console)

> **9.1.5. Using H2’s Web Console**
>
> The H2 database provides a browser-based console that Spring Boot can auto-configure for you. The console is auto-configured when the following conditions are met:
>
> - You are developing a servlet-based web application.
> - `com.h2database:h2` is on the classpath.
> - You are using Spring Boot’s developer tools.
>
> If you are not using Spring Boot’s developer tools but would still like to make use of H2’s console, you can configure the `spring.h2.console.enabled` property with a value of `true`.

You have to disable CSRF and set `X-Frame-Options`, see [Accessing the H2 Console in a Secured Application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#data.sql.h2-web-console.spring-security):

> **Accessing the H2 Console in a Secured Application**
>
> H2 Console uses frames and, as it is intended for development only, does not implement CSRF protection measures. If your application uses Spring Security, you need to configure it to
>
> - disable CSRF protection for requests against the console,
> - set the header `X-Frame-Options` to `SAMEORIGIN` on responses from the console.
>
> More information on CSRF and the header X-Frame-Options can be found in the Spring Security Reference Guide.
>
> In simple setups, a `SecurityFilterChain` like the following can be used:
>
> ```java
> @Profile("dev")
> @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
> public class DevProfileSecurityConfiguration {
>
>     @Bean
>     @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
>     SecurityFilterChain h2ConsoleSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>         http.securityMatcher(PathRequest.toH2Console());
>         http.authorizeHttpRequests(yourCustomAuthorization());
>         http.csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable());
>         http.headers((headers) -> headers.frameOptions().sameOrigin());
>         return http.build();
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try running with this below code snippet

```java
http
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/"), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/console/**"), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll();
http
    .csrf().disable();
http
    .headers()
        .frameOptions().disable();
http.build();
```

Comment: hi dur, if i replace this [.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**"))] with this [.requestMatchers("/h2-console/**")] same problem

Answer (score -1):

You should disable frameOptions. Here is full example code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;
    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    private final JWTAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(final AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.antMatchers("/api/admin").hasAuthority("ADMIN");
                    auth.antMatchers("/api/user").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER");
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/public",
                "/h2-console/**",
                "/api/auth/login",
                "/api/announcement",
                "/api/channel",
                "/api/message",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/swagger-ui.html/**",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/swagger-ui/**",
                "/v3/api-docs/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```