# My SecurityConfig do not work when using custom filters.(SpringBoot3)

Tags: filter, spring-security, spring-boot-3

In SpringBoot3..

This is my SecurityConfig

```java
    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authorize -> {
                            try {
                                authorize
                                        .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                                        .requestMatchers("/exception/**").permitAll()
                                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/sign-in", "/api/sign-up", "/api/refresh-token").permitAll()
                                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll()
                                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/members/{id}/**")
                                        .access((authentication, object) -> {
                                            String idAttr = object.getVariables().get("id");
                                            return new AuthorizationDecision(memberGuard.check(Long.parseLong(idAttr)));
                                        })
                                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/swagger-ui.html/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()
                                        .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN");
                            }catch (Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        })
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler())
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(accessTokenHelper, userDetailsService),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
```

When accessing the /h2-console, I set permitAll, but it goes to the CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint set in the authentication Entry Point.

This is My Custom JwtFilter

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final TokenHelper accessTokenHelper;
    private final CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = extractToken(request);
        if(validateToken(token)) {
            setAuthentication(token);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String extractToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader("Authorization");
    }

    private boolean validateToken(String token) {
        return token != null && accessTokenHelper.validate(token);
    }

    private void setAuthentication(String token) {
        String userId = accessTokenHelper.extractSubject(token);
        CustomUserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userId);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new CustomAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getAuthorities()));
    }

}
```

This is My CustomUserDetailsService

```java
@Component
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final MemberRepository memberRepository;


    @Override
    public CustomUserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userId) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Member member = memberRepository.findById(Long.valueOf(userId))
                .orElseGet(Member::anonymousMember);
        return new CustomUserDetails(
                String.valueOf(member.getId()),
                member.getRoleSet().stream().map(MemberRole::getAuthority)
                        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    }
}
```

Is there a problem?

I tried set AnonymousAuthenticaionFilter but it was not worked

```java
.anonymous().authenticationFilter(new AnonymousAuthenticationFilter("key", "anonymousUser",
AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ANONYMOUS")))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Security version 6 issues with SecurityFilterChain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76090520/spring-security-version-6-issues-with-securityfilterchain)

Comment: Oh... I solved the problem.. requestMatchers(PathRequest.toH2Conolse()) is working.. 
but i don't know diff..